how to improve the fps of screenshot using python(mss/pyautogui/PIL) on Macos?
I'm trying to acquire the screenshots continuously for some CV projects, but the fps is quite low.
Currently I'm using a 2019 macbook pro.
I tried pyautogui, mss and PIL. The mss library gave me around 3fps, which is my best result. It is way faster when taking partial screenshots.
Is this the common result? How can I improve this?
Base on answers form How to Capture Screen using Python with better frame rate, the solution from spl gave me around 8fps, but it also gets slower when I consider a bigger capture window.
Here is my code:
import PIL.ImageGrab
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
from mss.darwin import MSS as mss
from time import time

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

loop_time=time()
with mss() as sct:
    # monitor = {"top": 500, "left": 500, "width": 500, "height": 500}
    while True:
        # screenshot = sct.grab(monitor)
        filename = sct.shot()
        cv_image = cv.imread(filename)  # Read the screenshot file
        cv_image = cv.cvtColor(cv_image, cv.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)  # Convert from BGRA to BGR

        cv.imshow("screen", cv_image)

        print('FPS{}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
        loop_time = time()
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
            break
cv.destroyAllWindows()

I tried pyautogui, pil and mss.
I hope to achieve around 20 fps of complete screenshots

This question is similar to: How to Capture Screen using Python with better frame rate. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your timing also includes saving and loading a PNG file, displaying it, and checking key input. All of these things are slow. What will the FPS be when measured with just sct.grab(monitor)?
